# Qfield Package Help

Tags: qgis, tile-map-service

Is there anyway to take Google, Bing or Esri imagery and create a imagery package that will work in Qfield?

See Supported data formats below.

Spatialite
Geopackage
WMS
Postgis 
MBTiles
Shapefile
Tiff
ECW 
MrSID

Answer (score 1):

It would be enough to create a Tile server XYZ layer in the QGIS project; You need internet connection in the tablet !!!

video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DhOeekV6oBk&index=2&list=PLqDFjeQq7NBiBTHTXwQ5l0m1H1uy7Y-xm

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HhGwfA7M50&t=2s

EDIT:[image]

BING: http://h0.ortho.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/h{q}.jpeg?g=0

Comment: Thank you Sir, however do you have the link to Bing and google so I can add them to tile server?

Comment: BING: http://h0.ortho.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/h{q}.jpeg?g=0